# Is CompositionLocalProvider the only approach for custom Compose Theme?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on the Theme of an application which has its own design system. After reading the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/custom#implementing-fully-custom) about custom theming I have some doubts.

Is there any reason why the different specs are provided as a CompositionLocals? I understand in some cases like colors where there is a chance we need to trigger recomposition for something like (dark/light) but for Typographies why bother providing it through `CompositionLocal` and not access them directly from a static variable? **Having a custom Typography spec means using Material Components "[won't work](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/components/Button.kt)" anyway, right?**

For context the Typography spec would be something like XXL, XL, L, M, S..(insted of h1, h2..) with a prefidined sizes (weights, etc). It could be modeled has a global `object` that could be accessed from everywhere instead of a class that is provided... does it make sense?

Comment: Using current approach libraries can define default values for elements, like default button background color is `MaterialTheme.colors.primary`, without knowing actual runtime values.

Comment: yes, right, but as I said having a custom Color/Typo Spec (different from primary, secondary, etc.) using this Material Component becomes "useless" since they point to the material spec.. so you won't be benefiting from these defaults since not passing something would end up meaning using values from a different spec

Comment: Material values are only used in material elements. They are not part of Compose itself. If you don't use them, you don't have to use the values either, and you can define any color system you want.

Comment: "Is there any reason why the different specs are provided as a CompositionLocals?" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not great for Stack Overflow. Frequently, only Developer X can give an answer, with everyone else just guessing. "for Typographies why bother providing it through CompositionLocal and not access them directly from a static variable?" -- there is no requirement that the typography remain static for the life of the process. Perhaps in your app it will not change; in other apps, it might.

Answer (score 0):

***I use composition local for getting access to custom spacing anywhere as follows***

**Spacing.kt**

```
data class Spacing(
    val default : Dp = 0.dp,
    val extraSmall: Dp = 4.dp,
    val small: Dp = 8.dp,
    val large: Dp = 12.dp,
    val extraLarge: Dp = 16.dp,
)

val LocalSpacing = compositionLocalOf { Spacing() }

val MaterialTheme.spacing: Spacing
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalSpacing.current
```

***In*** **theme.kt**

```
@Composable
fun PokedexTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }
    
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalSpacing provides Spacing()
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

**Access it as**:

```
MaterialTheme.Spacing.large
```